# Making a 2D array toroidal

Tags: c, arrays, conways-game-of-life

How can I make the array toroidal (wrap bottom to top and left to right), i.e the leftmost cell is regarded as the rightmost cell, like [0][0] and [5][5] are the same cells in `int array[5][5]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'toridiality' (if that is actually a word) could be implemented by using an accessor function which does the mapping (by using the division remainder operator) instead of the bracket operators on the arrays directly. The function could be implemented as follows, where `m` and `n` are the number of rows and columns of `board`, respectively.

```
int GetElement(int i, int j)
{
    return board[i % m][j % n];
}
```

Comment: So this should be done first before all other functions? Create a toroidal 2D array and then my code stated in my question will work upon that new toroidal array?

Comment: This is just a sketch; the direct access via `[i][j]` would be replaced by `GetElement(i,j)`. Note that additional fine-tuning may be necessary if `i` and `j` are permitted to be negative.

Comment: Ah so for example `if (GetElement(i + 1, j + 1) == 1` etc?

Comment: Yes, exactly - the function 'makes the array toridial' by performing suitable index manipulation.

Comment: Awesome dude. Thank you. Amazing username by the way!